# Show Applications - Change icon size and/or grid

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I have a 4x6 grid when click on the Show Applications icon in Ubuntu 18.04.

The resulting icons look MASSIVE on my desktop.

Is there a way to either alter their size or, ideally, alter the grid dimensions so that more icons fit on each page (thereby reducing the icon size)?