# How do I change font size on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, lts

1. Does anyone know how to change the size of the fonts on icons on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?
2. How do I change the icon size of the icons that appear when the show applications button is pressed?

Thanks for any help given :)

Comment: icon size is customized in `gnome-shell.css` file of the shell theme you are using.. but it will only reduce or increase the size but not the grid size..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1091876/739431